# Is there an analogue to Rails partials in VB .NET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vb.net, partials

I'm new to VB .NET, and if possible, I'd like something like Rails partials - bits of HTML template that can be referenced in a page's script, possibly within a loop. I know there might not be anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

[User Controls](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/usercontrol15.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Castle Project is an interesting open source alternative to ASP.NET / ADO.NET. Among other things, the Castle Project provides a Rails-like development framework for .NET.
http://jamescrisp.blogspot.com/2007/06/castle-project-rails-for-net.html

Answer (score 0):

You can read html into a string, and spit it out with a placeholder / literal control. the function is like so:

```
Dim tmp as string = GetHtmlFragement()
Placeholder1.controls.add(New LiteralControl(tmp))
```